# Why is ArcMap deleting data from a field when I add a new one?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, table, fields-attributes

My copy of ArcMap 10 is acting pretty strangely. I have a shapefile and all I've done is added a new field as a FLOAT and for some reason all data in another one of my fields is being deleted! Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks,
Alan!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it happen again multiple times after restarting ArcMap? Have you tried using the Options menu in the Attribute table > Add Field instead of running a GP tool dialog?

Comment: It's happened a few times after restarting, and it's also occurring with the Add Field option too

Comment: And it is also occurring on a colleague, he has just linked me to this:

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41119

Comment: You have probably verified that, but out of curiousity - have you refreshed the Attribute table cache? (Options button > Reloac Cache)

Comment: Yeah, I assume you are on the latest SP for 10.0? SP5 I think?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am, not 100% though

Comment: have you tried converting the shapefile to a file geodatabase, and then going through this process?

Comment: It's definitely something to do with the software I used to export the file, I converted it to a TAB and back again and it worked fine!